# Simple way to calculate number of possible combinations if can remove x elements

Tags: combinatorics

This question came up in as a part of a research project that I'm involved in; I think there should be an obvious quick way to solve it, but I resorted to inelegantly solving it (not quite) by brute force.

The question is if I have x variables how many possible variations are there if I remove up to y variables. The order doesn't matter.

For example, if I have 4 variables - `a, b, c, d` - and I could remove up to 2 varaibales there would be some of the possible combinations:

```
a,b,c,d
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,0
1,1,0,1
1,0,1,1
0,1,1,1
1,1,0,0
1,0,1,0
...
```

Comment: Worded another way... you want the number of subsets of an $x$ element set of size up to $y$.  This is simply $\sum\limits_{k=0}^y\binom{x}{k}$.  A few special cases exist such as when $x=2y+1$ you would have this sum simplifies to $2^{x-1}$ or when $x=y$ you have the sum simplifies to $2^x$, but generally this sum does not simplify.

Comment: For more on this summation, [see this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n)